# Double clicking a google earth treeview node does not 'flyto' the placemark

Tags: google-earth-plugin

I am using the plugin in a desktop application (Visual Studio C#).  I am creating a placemark using the following code:

```
// Create a new coordinate object based on the lat/lon of the device
// TODO :: add lat/lon once data is available
FC.GEPluginCtrls.Geo.Coordinate Coord = 
     new FC.GEPluginCtrls.Geo.Coordinate(0, 0, 0, AltitudeMode.RelativeToGround);

// Create a placemark and put it in the tree.
kmlTreeView.ParseKmlObject(KmlHelpers.CreatePlacemark(
            ge,
            Coord,
            ((Device)DeviceList[i]).sSerialNum,  // ID
            ((Device)DeviceList[i]).sNickname,   // Name - shown in tree
            ((Device)DeviceList[i]).sName));     // Description - shown in bubble
```

In the TreeView the new nodes show up and when I double-click on them the bubble pops up with information in it but the view does not change.  I attempted to verify the property "public bool FlyToOnDoubleClickNode" as shown in the documentation but that property apparently does not exist in the version I am using (1.010).

When I was loading a KML file the double click worked as expected but ever since I've been manually adding the placemarks it does not work.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried manually assigning a `<LookAt>` or `<Camera>` ?
That should work

Edit: Well the `FlyToOnDoubleClickNode` is turned on by default, so your problems lie elsewhere

I do not know why you are having troubles with setting multiple LookAts. Have you tried assigning 'ids' to your `LookAt` ? Depending on what you are actually doing, that might help.

Otherwise, have you seen [setFlyToView()](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/reference/interface_kml_network_link)

I am not sure that will help you though, since it relates to KMLs loaded via NetworkLinks

Thats about me for ideas - good luck!

Comment: I have not - I don't even know where to start.  Which API would I use to add those?

Comment: Ok, so I found the method "KmlHelpers.CreateLookAt()".  It works great the first time but the second time I click on a treeview node I get an exception - I'm assuming I can't create another LookAt - even if it is for a different node.  I really just need the "FlyTo" function that is supposedly in there...

Comment: Thanks for your help but I still haven't been able to fix my problem.  I don't know what I'm doing wrong but somehow I've broken the default behavior.

Comment: I just noticed that the "FlyToObject" method is called by default in the "OnNodeMouseDoubleClick" method.  It also calls the "OpenFeatureBalloon".  The latter seems to be working while the former does not.  ??

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the coordinates 0,0 are somehow significant.  If the coordinates are changed to something else the "FlyTo" works (0.1 and 0.1 work).